# Why is Matlab allocating so much memory?

Tags: matlab, memory, allocation

I used to run 5-6 Matlab instances on a server (Win Server 2008) and they allocated about 50-60Mb each. Now, as I plan to run up to 10 instances simultaneously, I upgraded the server RAM from 1 to 2 GB (running on a VPS) on a Win Server 2012 platform. Now after migrating to the new platform, I see that each Matlab instance is allocating more than 100Mb or RAM each, some up to 150Mb, meaning that the whole migration feels useless. Why is this the case? Does Matlab simply allocate whatever is available, or?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both operating systems 64 bit?

Comment: Win Server 2008 is 32 bit and 2012 is 64 bit, as far as I know. The Matlab version I'm running is 32 bit.

Comment: Upgrading to 2 GB on a server seems tiny, especially considering today's RAM prices. Most desktop computers have a lot more than that.

Comment: Yes, but this is a 3rd party VPS provider hence I cannot go and installing additional RAM myself... :-( My question is just why Matlab seems to allocate so much memory whereas an app written in C++ doing the same job allocates like 1-2 Mb of RAM?!?

Comment: See also Matlab's [Parallel computing toolbox](http://nl.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/)